# How to uninstall the Youtube lens?

Tags: 11.10, lenses, youtube

**Original title:** Well, I installed a lens for Youtube and cant figure out how to uninstall it.

I do not exactly which site I used to install the script for the Youtube lens, but I cannot get it to play anything. The lens works as far as searching and finding what I want but aside from that, it won't do anything else. I don't know if you can help out, but it would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: I should say also that VLC doesn't open or anything. I click on a video in the lens and simply nothing happens. :(

Comment: Okay, since I had added the launchpad ppa to my software sources all I had to do was open Ubuntu Software Center > Installed Programs > search "lens" > and look for the package for the "video" lens and then uninstall it. Sometimes I feel like a noob :(  (PS: I am unable to mark this question as solved since I am still not cool enough ;)

May the force be with you!

Comment: You can also delete the PPA with ppa-purge (command line only), it will delete the PPA from your system and revert any package to the official one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you can try synaptic package manager
(search for it in the Ubuntu software center) .

Comment: Thank you, that is what I managed to figure out...however I do not yet have the 'privileges' to answer my own questions within 8 hours or something like that. Thank you again, "Live long and prosper"